# Safari webinspector show blank window at remote debugging (iOS6 + iOS7)

Tags: ios, safari, remote-debugging

Testing my webpages with an iPad, I ran into an design error that only occurs on iOS devices. So I tried using the remote debugging feature that is available since iOS6.

- Macbook Pro: early '11, OSX Lion (10.7.5), Safari up-to-date (6.1.3)
- iPad 3: iOS 7.0.4 vanilla
- iPhone 4s: iOS 7.0.4 + jailbreak
- and iOS-Simulator (iOS 6) by Xcode.

It doesnt matter what device I use and what site i try to inspect, the remote webinspector is blank all the time. See the [attached screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yjwqA.png) (running OSX in german). I used google as an example in my screenshot.

What am I doing wrong?!

Comment: Same for me with Mavericks and completely up to date software.

Comment: Same for me Safari 7.1 and and IOS 8.0.2

Answer (score 15):

I had exactly the same issue with Safai 8.0 on MacOS 10.10.1 and iOS 8.1.2.

**Solution:**

Ensure that `cookies` are allowed in your desktop Safari.