# Blank screen on Safari remote debugging iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, web-applications, safari, remote-debugging

I'm trying to use Safari Web Inspector for remote debugging of a web application, and I keep getting a blank page in Web Inspector. Help!

**Things that get me a blank page:**

- actual device connected to my computer by USB
- all simulated devices through XCode
- intranet sites
- localhost sites
- publicly available sites
- in short: EVERYTHING.

**Things I have tried:**

- restarting everything (computer, iPad, XCode, Safari)
- updating all my software
- using Webkit nightly build
- checking iPad Settings > Safari > Advanced > Web Inspector (it's on)
- verifying iPad Safari is not in Private mode
- desktop Safari private browsing
- desktop Safari un-private browsing
- lots and LOTS of googling

I did find [a question asked here four months ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22982641/safari-webinspector-show-blank-window-at-remote-debugging-ios6-ios7), with no answers, and only one "me too!" three months later.

**Software versions:**

- Macbook Pro, OS 10.9.4
- Safari 7.0.6 (or Webkit nightly)
- XCode 5.1.1 (5B1008)
- iOS Simulator 7.1 (463.9.41)
- actual iPad iOS 7.1.2

FWIW, I am running the built-in Apache WebServer on my Mac, and I have had some user permissions problems on my Mac in the past.

Any help appreciated. I'm pretty stuck.

Comment: having the same problem: [link on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22982641/safari-webinspector-show-blank-window-at-remote-debugging-ios6-ios7)

Answer (score 5):

I had exactly the same issue with Safai 8.0 on MacOS 10.10.1 and iOS 8.1.2.

**Solution:**

Ensure that `cookies` are allowed in your desktop Safari.

Comment: Care to elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

Am not 100% sure what is the problems you are struggling with, I recently worked on iPad these steps helped me during the development, but make sure that nothing is missed if you go through this list :

**How to open Web Inspector for web apps running locally in mac system accessed over iPad/iPhone ?**

1. Connect your iPad to mac system with usb cable.
2. Open Safari in mac system, make sure that Develop menu is enabled, if its not enabled go to Preferences and then click advanced tab, check mark **Show Develop menu in menu bar**.
3. Open settings in iPad/iPhone select Safari and click Advanced to enable **Web Inspector**.
4. After that make sure that iPad and mac system is using the same network **(same Wifi router)**.
5. Click on Develop menu in Safari on mac system, you will see your iPad/iPhone listed in menu bar, click on iPad/iPhone and enable **Connect via Network**
6. Only if you're developing web apps with **webpack-dev-server**, also bind your **webpack-dev-server** to **0.0.0.0** instead of localhost. Changing the IP address to 0.0.0.0 will make your server externally accessible (within the same WiFi), for this you can add this change while running apps through webpack-dev-server **“webpack-dev-server --host 0.0.0.0”**
7. Now run any web app locally on mac system, and note down the ip address of network you’re connected with.
8. Now open Safari in iPad/iPhone and hit this url **https://ip-address:port** port should be the one on which you’re running web app locally on mac system, this way you have pointed your iPad/iPhone to your local system and you can access same web app running locally on your mac system.
9. To debug and inspect html pages, click on your device name within Safari Develop menu bar in your mac system and the page that you want to debug and inspect it will open open the Web inspector in the mac system.

For further details please go through this link, it was very helpful https://silvantroxler.ch/2018/wireless-remote-debugging-with-safari-on-ios/

I hope something will come up that can be helpful for you.